# Запятая или знак восклицания после слова "смотри" в значении обращать внимание на что-то?

Tags: пунктуация

В каком предложении знак пунктуации употреблен правильно после слова *смотри*?

> Смотри, я приготовлю ужин, а ты помоешь посуду.
>
> Смотри! Я приготовлю ужин, а ты помоешь посуду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С запятой предложение больше похоже на договоренность, а с восклицательным знаком - на угрозу. :) Или на эмоциональное высказывание. В обоих случаях - фразы из прямой речи, поэтому интонацией этой речи и надо руководствоваться, возможны оба варианта.

Я бы сказала, что восклицательный знак более типичен для фраз, где мы предлагаем физически посмотреть на что-то удивительное. 
"**Смотри! Там белка! Маленькая, рыжая, с длинным хвостом!**"